# How to set gradle 2.4 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I m curently developing an android app in which i m using android studio 2.1.1 as editor and i want to upgrade the gradle version from 2.1 to 2.4 so how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

you can edit the following file in your project:

```
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

then you edit this line to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

not yet sure why you would want to use 2.4 though - most recent is 2.14.1

Comment: i think i have a confusion btw gradle and it is plagin

Comment: 2.1 for the gradle plugin